# nginx is wrongly serving all subdomains

Tags: nginx

My nginx server is serving content to all subdomains, even though I've removed the default_server from the main server block.

So there is absolutely no reference whatsoever to "default_server" or (for example) to subdomain.domain.com in any of the nginx config files and yet, if I go to that URL, it gives me the first site which is listening on port 80 (which specifies a different subdomain in the nginx config).

It's confusing the hell out of me - I want it to stop giving me anything on that domain so that I can then point that new subdomain to a new location.

Any ideas?!

Comment: We need a lot more detail to help here.  Configuration, relevant logs, specific examples, etc.

Comment: OK, well I'm pretty new to nginx so which logs do I need? At a very basic level though, I thought that if "subdomain.domain.com" wasn't in any of the conf files, and there was no default_server, then nginx wouldn't serve anything at all to that subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no `default_server` defined, `nginx` will use the first server it finds as the default server, so this behavior is standard and expected. If you don't want that, define a  `default-server` that is to be used and which might just return some error if you want this.

Comment: Ahah! Of course. Why on earth didn't I think of that?! Brilliant, thanks.